# Angular 2 Log Framework that pushes logs to server

Tags: angular, logging, server, logstash

I'm looking for an angular2 logging framework that will ultimately push the logs to the server or use appenders like logstash to push the logs. Also I want the framework in such a way that in case of internet connectivity issue, it should retry to push the logs(If the timestamp remains to the initial logging time that will be an additional bonus). Any recommendation is much appreciated.

I'm currently looking at ngx-logger to push the logs to the server, but I'm not sure if the retry mechanism is available in that.

Comment: [Loggly](https://www.loggly.com/blog/angular-exception-logging-made-simple/)?

Comment: Ya I did see that. But it seems too costly. But Thanks for that suggestion. Can you think something else which is relatively cheaper. :)